# jQuery-How to know if dynamic content/tag is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, edit

I am working on some extension where I am listening for dynamic contents being inserted and am using these two methods.

```
searchTag = 'tagtosearch'
$(document).on ('DOMNodeInserted', searchTag,{}, function(e){

});

$(document).arrive(searchTag, function(){

});
```

Both work fine. The second version is a separate library from [Here](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive)

What am interested is in some attributes for this tag and when callback is called the attributes from `this` might still be undefined.

To solve this am using `setTimeout` where I check whether the attribute is undefined or not if defined I stop there or I call it again.

```
searchTag = 'tagtosearch'

function foo (node, timeout) 
{
    var valid = function () {} // check if attribute is undefined or not.

    if (valid) {
        // do my stuff here.
    } else {
        setTimeout(foo, timeout, node, timeout);    
    }
}

$(document).on ('DOMNodeInserted', searchTag,{}, function(event){
    setTimeout(foo, 100, this, 100);
});
```

Is there any other alternative way to do this, instead of calling `foo` after every timeout millisecond.
If not is this way is better?

Comment: `$(searchTag).on("load", function(){ // Do Stuff });`

Comment: @Miron doesn't works.

Comment: Let me check how you add tags dynamically. Did you use `appendTo` or other method?

Comment: I am making a extension for youtube. As you scroll down new videos dynamically gets added.

Comment: @Miron and i am listening for those insertions